# Angular data from controller into modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a controller that looks as following:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.items = [{name:'Category1', children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312',
                          'CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','CZEC-1311','CZEC-1312',
                          'FREN-1311','FREN-1312','FREN-1411','GERM-1311','GERM-1312',
                          'GERM-1411','GREE-1412','ITAL-1412','JAPN-1412','KORE-1412',
                          'LATI-1412','PORT-1412','RUSS-1412','SGNL-1301','SGNL-1302',
                          'SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311',
                          'VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412']},
                          {name:'Category2', children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312',
                          'CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311',
                          'VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412']}];

    $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
};
```

and my modal looks like the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{subcategory.name2}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                <font size="2" align="center">Required Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb">{{subcategory.required2}} </span>
                        Completed Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb">{{subcategory.completed2}} </span>
                        Planned Credits : <span class="badge badge-machb">{{subcategory.planned2}} </span></font>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question is how do i define buttons in such a way that it display it displays the children of the contents of "Category1" when a button named "category1" is clicked ina a modal and "Category2" when the corresponding is clicked?

The planned, required and completed credits in the above modal are from another controller and hence it can be neglected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite straightforward. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TYAjkvuFM90VdO3Zvpik?p=preview) to get a complete view of my discussion below.

1. Iterate the items via ng-repeat and display each `item.category` as a button which is bound by an ng-click event and pass the index of the item to be used for the modal to resolve.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="open($index)"></button>
</body>
```

1. The html fragment above suggests that the ng-click event callback `open()` must accept the current $index of the iterated items. Use the $index to get the specific category and pass it to the modal's controller `ModalInstanceCtrl` $scope to be used by the `myModalContent.html` template.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.items = [{name:'Category1', children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312',
                  'CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','CZEC-1311','CZEC-1312',
                  'FREN-1311','FREN-1312','FREN-1411','GERM-1311','GERM-1312',
                  'GERM-1411','GREE-1412','ITAL-1412','JAPN-1412','KORE-1412',
                  'LATI-1412','PORT-1412','RUSS-1412','SGNL-1301','SGNL-1302',
                  'SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311',
                  'VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412']},
                  {name:'Category2', children:['SPCH-1311','SPCH-1315','SPCH-1321','ARAB-1311','ARAB-1312',
                  'CHIN-1312','CHIN-1411','CHIN-1412','SPAN-1311','SPAN-1312','SPAN-1411','SPAN-1412','VIET-1311',
                  'VIET-1312','VIET-1411','VIET-1412']}];

  $scope.open = function ($index) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        item: function() {
          return $scope.items[$index];
        }
      }
    });
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {
   $scope.item = item;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but here it goes. It seems like you want it so that when you click a button, it will display the children of one of your categories. So, here's the code for that.

HTML to display a button for each category:

```
<button  ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="displayChildren(item)"  ng-bind="item.name"></button>
```

UL to display the children when you select the button:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="child in children" ng-bind="child"></li>
</ul>
```

The code in the controller:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        name: "category1",
        children: [
            "CHIN-1",
            "CHIN-2",
            "CHIN-3"
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "category2",
        children : [
            "VIET-1",
            "VIET-2",
            "VIET-3"
        ]
    }];

$scope.displayChildren = function(item){
    $scope.children = item.children;
}
```